# Embedded OLEO-Object overwrites itself when edited

Tags: excel, vba, templates, powerpoint, presentation

Im currently trying to do the following steps:

1. Have a PowerPoint-Template Embedded Into Excel
2. Run A finished macro that edits the PP-Template
3. Save the newly edited PP as a new PP-File
4. Be able to repeat steps 1-3 if wanted

To do this I have embedded the PP-Template as an OLEO-Object (via Insert-->Object-->Choose PPTX) named "PPtemplate" on a Worksheet called "PP Export" and run the following code:

```
'Dim oEmbFile As Object
'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
'Set oEmbFile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PP Export").OLEObjects("PPtemplate")
'oEmbFile.Verb Verb:=xlOpen
'Set oEmbFile = Nothing
'Set PPpres = PPapp.ActivePresentation
'Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

This works very well, except I can only do this once. This is because once the first macro edits the template, it automatically saves these changes and the template is not the template anymore but rather the result of the first macro run (edited template)...

How can I stop it from overriding itsself? Maybe somehow extract the template to the User-PC then open and edit it, so the embedded template is always the same even after you run the macro?

Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks and stay healthy

EDIT - Solution:

1. Asking for Saving Place
2. Save copy of embedded
3. open copy to edit copy instead of embedded file

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
   .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
     PPdateipfad = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
End With

Dim oEmbFile As Object
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set oEmbFile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PP Export").OLEObjects("PPvorlage")
oEmbFile.Verb Verb:=xlOpen
Set oEmbFile = Nothing
Set PPpres = PPapp.ActivePresentation
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
PPpres.SaveAs (PPdateipfad + "\QM-Check Präsentation.pptx")
PPpres.Close
Set PPpres = PPapp.Presentations.Open(PPdateipfad + "\QM-Check Präsentation.pptx")
```

Comment: Why can't you save the file first, then edit it? Why are you trying to do this anyway? Can't you get the same effect with a VBA-enabled presentation that save itself as a template?

Comment: Can I save the PP from within Excel VBA? I want both in one file, which is why I embedded it (the PP-Template) into the Excel File and the PP-template is and should not be VBA-enabled as it doesnt contain any macros, I do it all from excel

Comment: You haven't explained why Excel is part of the mix. You can create a single file that is a macro-enabled presentation that saves a copy of itself as a non-macro-enabled template. Or, if you must use Excel for some undisclosed purpose, save the PowerPoint file first, then open it in VBA and modify it.

Comment: I need Excel because it contains the data that fills the PowerPoint. I solved the problem in the way you proposed (see edit), thanks for your tips and Ill try to explain in even more detail next time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1. Asking for Saving Place
2. Save copy of embedded
3. open copy to edit copy instead of embedded file

```
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
   .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Show
     PPdateipfad = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
End With

Dim oEmbFile As Object
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Set oEmbFile = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PP Export").OLEObjects("PPvorlage")
oEmbFile.Verb Verb:=xlOpen
Set oEmbFile = Nothing
Set PPpres = PPapp.ActivePresentation
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
PPpres.SaveAs (PPdateipfad + "\QM-Check Präsentation.pptx")
PPpres.Close
Set PPpres = PPapp.Presentations.Open(PPdateipfad + "\QM-Check Präsentation.pptx")
```